# iOS Cloud Storage API for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: ios, wpf, visual-studio-2010, azure, icloud

I have created a WPF application using Visual Studio 2010 that receives data and sends the same to a Windows Azure Server (where the data is stored in tables). I am able to send and receive data on my Windows Phone 7 using the same using a service function I created.

However, I now need to send data from this application and receive it on an iOS device (in an iOS app). Are there any APIs for Visual Studio that let you send data to an iOS cloud storage space.

If not, are there any APIs that enable an iPhone app to receive/pull data from an Azure Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Windows Azure Mobile Services](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/) includes an iOS SDK (along with Android, Windows Phone, Windows 8, and JavaScript) for storing data (as well as authentication and push notifications on those platforms).  That presumes though that you're leveraging the storage that's part of Windows Azure Mobile Services, and it sounds like you've already got an alternative storage solution in Azure - though it wasn't clear if you were using SQL Database or table storage.

By leveraging [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/odata.aspx) or the [Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api) you could expose your existing Azure data via OData which is an open protocol (REST-ful) for which there are many client libraries including [iOS](http://www.odata.org/libraries/ios/).  Since you already have an existing storage solution, this service wrapper approach may be easier and quicker than migrating to Azure Mobile Services.